# "Node-independent path"?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I am solving the following problem in graph theory.

> Suppose that A and B are vertices in a network and that you can
> identify two node-independent paths between them. Is it always the
> case that if you pick one vertex in each path at random and remove it
> (and edges connected to it), the vertices will be disconnected? If so,
> explain why. if not, give an example.

What does "node-independent paths" mean here, and what does it mean that we can "identify" them? I am not a native English speaker, so I am not sure if the issue is my mathematical ability or my English ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Node-independent*, also *vertex-independent*, means the two paths do not share any nodes (vertices).

That is, the two paths are completely separate except for their start and end nodes. Also equivalently, the union of the paths is a circuit, and the intersection of the paths is exactly the start and end nodes.

See for example, the definitions provided at [Analytic Tech's graph theory introduction](http://www.analytictech.com/networks/graphtheory.htm) or in the introduction to [this paper on the connection between connectivity and vertex-independent paths](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1831790).